# preg_match_all to find url in string

Tags: php, regex

I get may Data from XML file. I need to Output only the URL´s from the Strings in my array. In format like 'https://d1.cloudfront.net/00722.jpg' without the other tags and styles arround. I have try that with preg_match_all but i get no results.
What i doing wrong?

```html
public function xmlParserPICtn():string
{
    
    $valuesPICtn = $this->xml->xpath("//OBJEKT[@ID='91727']//PICTURE"); 
    $searchpattern="@SRC=(.*)width@";
    preg_match_all($searchpattern, $valuesPICtn, $valuesPICt); //Search-String
    foreach ($valuesPICt as $PICelements) 
      {
         $display .= '<li>';
         $display .= ''.$PICelements->PIC.'';
         $display .= '</li>';
            
        }
     $display .= '';

      return $display;
  }
  
  
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OBJEKT ID="91727">
    
          <PICTURE ID="7">
              <ID>7</ID>
                  <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00722.jpg" width="610" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
                 </PICTURE>
    
         <PICTURE ID="11">
              <ID>11</ID>
                  <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/01123.jpg" width="630" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
                 </PICTURE>
    
         <PICTURE ID="2">
                  <ID>2</ID>
                  <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00224.jpg" width="740" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
                 </PICTURE>
    
         <PICTURE ID="9">
                  <ID>9</ID>
                  <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00925.jpg" width="940" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
                 </PICTURE>
    
</OBJEKT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop the result of the xpath query that is in `valuesPICtn`

Then for every item in the loop, there is `$PICelements->PIC` that has a single picture. You can use preg_match instead, and take the group 1 value. Note that the second parameter of [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) take a string, where you tried to pass the return of the xpath call in your code.

Note that this part in your code `$display .= '';` can be omitted as it concats an empty string.

The pattern `SRC="([^"]+)"` is a slightly updated version, matching SRC=" and captures in group 1 any char other than a double quote

```
public function xmlParserPICtn():string
{
    $valuesPICtn = $this->xml->xpath("//OBJEKT[@ID='91727']//PICTURE");
    foreach ($valuesPICtn as $PICelements)
    {
        $searchpattern='@SRC="([^"]+)"@';
        preg_match($searchpattern, $PICelements->PIC, $valuesPICt); //Search-String
        $display .= '<li>';
        $display .= $valuesPICt[1];
        $display .= '</li>';
    }
    return $display;
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/d1VFJ)

Comment: Amazing! Your solution work fine. Thank you verry much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex :

```
(?<=SRC=")(.*?)(?=\")
```

I get only the URL without the other tags.

You found here the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8gmg2V/1)

Comment: This does not answer the question at all, with this change the code still does not work. Also note that if you use the lookarounds, you don't need a capture group.